# Assign Bottle sizes based upon store in multi-store

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, multistore, products-management

I have 150 configurable products.  Each product has bottle sizes ranging from 10ml to 5kg.  I have set up two stores: Wholesale and Retail.  I am trying to show all bottle sizes in wholesale store with wholesale pricing. And then show only 3 sizes of bottles with retail pricing in the retail store.

I have tried assigning them on a per store basis, but it still shows all sizes in both stores.

Do I need to make a duplicate set of all the configurable products on a store by store basis?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this the way you have described you would need to duplicate the configurable product for wholesale and retail, with the retail product only having the three product (bottle) sizes.

A more flexible approach would be to create a Wholesale and Retail customer group, and then apply logic on the Configurable product to only display the child product options that are applicable to the group, i.e. all the child products (bottle sizes) for Wholesale, only 3 for Retail etc.

If you have already created two shops then this might not be practical. So you would need to apply the logic base on the store the customer is in, or duplicate the products...

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I need to duplicate the configurable products.  I do however, already have a wholesale and retail customer groups.  I cannot find where you suggested I can set the display of child items (bottle sizes) specific to each store and for each customer group.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes more sense to create two separate websites instead of just stores. This gives you more flexibility with store specific product configuration like prices and tax.

You can disable the simple products that should not appear on website level. By default, configurable products only show the options where there actually is a simple *salable* product.

Actually, disabling products (status attribute) if also possible on store level. So if that's not working for you, you have some modification in the configurable product page that doesn't use the default logic.